# Javascript timer help needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I have the following ajax page. The form should be submitted and the timer should be restart counting down when the timer expires or button is clicked.
For some reason the timer is not reset and goes minus. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

(The code is standalone, you can copy/paste ans test it, then run it on server)

**`test.htm:`**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mootools.net/download/get/mootools-core-1.3-full-compat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<form id="form" name="form" action="test.htm" method="post">
Remaining time: <input type="text" name="clock" size="4">seconds
<input type="submit" value="submit" ID="questionSubmit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeLeft = 10;
function startClock() {
    timeLeft--;
    document.form.clock.value = timeLeft;
    if(timeLeft == 0) {
        sendForm();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout("startClock()", 1000);
    }
}

setTimeout("startClock()", 1000);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e = new Event(e).stop();
    sendForm();
}

function sendForm() {
    $('form').set('send', {onComplete: function(response) {
        $('container').set('html', response);
        $('questionSubmit').addEventListener('click', handleSubmit, false);
        setTimeout("startClock()", 1000);
    }});
    //Send the form.
    $('form').send();
}

$('questionSubmit').addEventListener('click', handleSubmit, false);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first guess is that you should use <= 0 instead of ==, in case you somehow skip over 0.

Comment: If I do that `sendForm();` is called every second

Comment: It does not count negative for me. Also, the send() seems to work as well.

Comment: unrelated, but replace setTimeout("startClock()", 1000); with setTimeout(startClock, 1000); this will make your code not be from 1999

Comment: Is it supposed to redirect you (form submit)? Or is it supposed to be an AJAX submit? (probably not). Why do you want to reset the timer when the page is being left (on submit) anyway?

Comment: @Kissaki what browser did you use? I'm using firefox

Comment: @kissaki what happens when the timer is 0? You should put this on a web server, if I test it on local machine I get a white page when timer expires(I guess it can not load test.htm).

Comment: this is a perfect example of when you should use `setInterval` instead and `clearInterval` when needed. also, what @mkoryak said. also, for mootools pre 1.3, you tend to use `.delay` and `.periodical`, as well as accessing properties should be via .set and .get and not direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following additions fixed it:
`<input id="timeLeft" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" />`
...

`function sendForm() {

/.../

timeLeft = document.getElementById('timeLeft').value;

/.../

}`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should use `<=0`. As you replied, `sendForm()` is then called every second. This doesn't make sense, so I suspect there's something else going on

My second observation is that you're never resetting `timeLeft`. A good place for this would be following the call to `sendForm`

Comment: `timeLeft` should come from the next page(ie after `sendForm()` is called and response is loaded), so at that instant I do not know the value.

Comment: ok, putting a hardcoded value for `timeLeft` after `sendForm()` worked. Now the question is how do I get this value out of `response`